# What does tuple assignment `var (x:p,y:q)=("","")` in Swift?

Tags: swift, tuples

In Swift, we assign tuples like this `var (x,y):(String,String)=("","")` or omit the type decl `var (x,y)=("","")`; but what does `var (x:p,y:q)=("","")` mean? It compiles is Swift 5.3.3 and treat p and q as variables, it's so weird.

Anybody can explain this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the following, can you think of something?

```
var (x: p, y: q) = (x: "", y: "")
```

You know, in Swift, tuples may have labels.
And in the current implementation of Swift, Swift compiler treats `x` and `y` are the labels of the tuple in the example you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
var (x:p,y:q)=("","")
```

You declare 2 variables, p and q, that are part of an tuple and their type is implicitly given by the initial values, "". This tuple also has labels x and y.

This could also has been declared with an explicit type

```
var (x: p, y: q): (x: String, y: String)
```

Now you can use the variables either as an tuple or on their own

```
(p, q) = ("foo", "bar")
q = "bar"
(x: p, y: q) = ("foo", "bar")
(x: p, y: q) = (x: "foo", y: "bar")
```