# Why does this code create a circular reference?

Tags: swift, circular-reference

First, thanks for your Help

```
for _ in 0..<v {
    let edge = readLine()!.split(separator: " ").map { Int(String($0))! }
    let (a: Int, b: Int, w: Int) = (edge[0], edge[1], edge[2]) 
}
```

It seems to me that it is simply the process of receiving integers and putting them in the tuple, but a Circular reference error is detected. Can you tell me why?

```
let edge = readLine()!.split(separator: " ").map { Int(String($0))! }
let (a, b, w) = (edge[0], edge[1], edge[2])
```

It works well if I remove the type annotations.

Comment: According to the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977604/what-does-tuple-assignment-var-xp-yq-in-swift it seems that this syntax is trying to declare multiple variables named `Int` and a tuple with labels a, b and w.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is sort of unclear, but syntax `let (a: Int, b: Int, w: Int)` is not valid for declaring the types of variables inside the tuple. You are effectively declaring 3 variables named `Int` with no type. And `a` and `b` are just labels you'd be able to refer by `continue a` or `break b`, except that would also be problematic, since those labels are inside the tuple.

You could do one of the following instead:

**Option 1**:

```
let (a, b, w): (Int, Int, Int) = (edge[0], edge[1], edge[2])
print(a, b, w)
```

This is not even a tuple - we defined 3 independent variables - `a`, `b`, and `w`, all of type `Int`

**Option 2**:

```
let x: (a: Int, b: Int, w: Int) = (edge[0], edge[1], edge[2])
print(x.a, x.b, x.w)
```

In this case we define a single variable `x`, of type tuple with 3 elements, labeled `a`, `b` and `w`. Notice that we refer to them via `x`

**Option 2a**:
We may as well do this: define our type once

```
typealias MyType = (a: Int, b: Int, w: Int)
```

and then use it multiple times:

```
for _ in 0..<v {
    let edge = readLine()!.split(separator: " ").map { Int(String($0))! }
    let x: MyType = (edge[0], edge[1], edge[2]) 
}
```

Comment: You also don't need explicit typing. (`let x: (a: _, b: _, w: _) = (edge[0], edge[1], edge[2])` or `let x = (a: edge[0], b: edge[1], w: edge[2])`)

Comment: Thanks to you, I've grown even more